# How can the hypernaturals be constructed from the naturals (or integers/ hyperintegers)

Tags: natural-numbers, ordered-fields

I want to find a construction of ${}^*\mathbb N$, that does not involve the reals, because my interest is in using the hypernaturals as a step towards an alternative construction of $\mathbb R$ as a subset of ${}^*\mathbb Q$. My reasoning is that since ${}^*\mathbb N$ is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb N$, the following construction should be more intuitive and believable then a construction that starts by "observing reals are equivalent to their decimal expansions" or any similar assumption. I believe the same could be said of ${}^*\mathbb Z$ if this is easier.

For context this isn't a nonstandard analysis question (which seems to have developed its own standard) and I'm hoping that the construction can be described mostly in layman's terms, and preferably with a few examples that explain which numbers are and are not considered part of ${}^*\mathbb N$. Perhaps in the context of ordinals.

My thought process so far has led me to some idea that ${}^*\mathbb N$ can be constructed as an ordered subset of $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ (ordered infinite sequences of naturals equivalent to functions over $\mathbb N$), however since I haven't been able to pin down exactly what elements are supposed to be ${}^*\mathbb N$, I haven't been able to convince myself that any of the subsets I've looked at even have the correct cardinality. for instance multiplicative, additive, and subtractive combinations of $c$, $x$, $x^2$, … $x^x$ etc. seems to still only be countable.

Comment: I don't know of any construction of ${}^*\mathbb{N}$ that _does_ involve the reals in any non-superficial way.  Have you seen any construction of it at all?

Comment: @EricWofsey I suspect the OP has in mind the construction of ${}^*\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ and then the extraction of ${}^*\mathbb{N}$ from *that*. Of course this is an unnecessary detour.

Comment: You say "${}^*\Bbb N$ has the same structure as $\Bbb N$". Is that really true?

Comment: If "structure" has a mathematically rigorous standard definition, then probably not. When I said structure I meant that based on what I've read \*ℕ is supposed to preserve certain statements about ℕ. for instance: every natural has a successor, also applies to \*ℕ.

Comment: @inventPie That’s called being elementarily equivalent (obeys the same first order sentences). “Has the same structure” sounds like it should mean “isomorphic” which is not the case.

Comment: I suppose I see why "structure" may be a misleading choice of word, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 4):

Identifying a particular subset of $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$, and defining operations on it, is going to be... tricky.

For example, assume that $x=(0,1,2,3,\ldots)$ is in your set. Is $x$ an even number or an odd number? If you define addition on $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ as simple coordinate-wise addition, then it is neither; there is no $y$ such that $y+y=x$ or $y+y+1=x$. But then, $x$ isn't a hypernatural number!

You might try to rescue the situation by saying, we'll declare that $x$ is even, and $x/2=y=(0,0,1,1,\ldots)$, and to make that work, we'll identify $y+y=(0,0,2,2,\ldots)$ with $x$ on the grounds that the two sequences agree infinitely often. Ah, but they also disagree infinitely often... Well, more specifically, the two sequences agree on even coordinates, and we're arbitrarily choosing to declare that when comparing sequences, the even coordinates matter more than the odd coordinates. Notice that by identifying different sequences, we are no longer choosing a subset of $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$, but rather a quotient of $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ by some equivalence relation.

Next someone will ask you whether $x$ is a power of $2$; whether it's a factorial; whether it's a Fibonacci number...

...and you'll have to do the same thing for every dichotomy of the natural numbers: to decide which side of the dichotomy matters more, and to do it in a consistent fashion, while ensuring that $x$ never becomes equivalent to a finite number...

...and long story short, you've wound up with a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$, and your hypernatural numbers will be the corresponding ultrapower. This is the standard construction. Further info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct

Comment: This clarifies that every question I can ask about an integer should also apply to every hyperinteger, this does make things trickier than I had thought. I'm still confused about what the "free ultrafilter" is, and what the hyperintegers will look like after I pick one (given more than one choice), are there other constructions? Also is it wrong or impossible to associate a quotient space with a subset containing canonical forms?

Comment: Under the Continuum Hypothesis, a saturation argument shows that all ultrapowers of $\mathbb{R}$ over a free ultrafilter are isomorphic: I suppose the same would hold for ultrapowers of $\mathbb{N}$. I'm not sure what you're asking, though.

Comment: from what I understand a free ultrafilter is a particular set, so If I construct \*ℕ using this method I'll need to find one of these sets, otherwise I won't be able to say whether or not x=(1,2,3,4...) is even or odd (assuming x is in \*ℕ). In order to work with these numbers, it's helpful to understand how particular elements behave, as opposed to just knowing that different versions are essentially the same. And I've never liked the idea of simply assuming the Continuum Hypothesis, it doesn't seem simple enough to be taken as an axiom on its own.

Comment: @inventPie: One needs the axiom of choice to even prove that free ultrafilters over $\mathbb N$ _exist_; it is consistent with ZF set theory that there may be none. That is a pretty good reason to expect that you'll never be able to _describe_ any free ultrafilter concretely.

Comment: I see... What dos this mean for the construction of \*ℕ? Can I still make statements about elements of \*ℕ, or does this mean that I don't really know what happens beyond ordinary integers? I'm also curious whether it does actually make sense to ask if x is a Fibonacci Number when these numbers are defined by adding regular integers in succession.

Comment: @inventPie You can ask about Fibonacci numbers either in regard to the ultrapower construction, or internally. Regarding the construction, $x$ is a Fibonacci number iff the set of Fibonacci numbers is in your filter. Assuming ZFC, you can choose an ultrafilter where this is either true of false. Regarding the internal view, consider that for all $n$, there exists a Fibonacci number between $n$ and $2n$. Now, regarding the broader question of *why* we should expect recursive definitions to "just work" in the hypernatural numbers, that's worthy of a separate question!